# load json with fetch instead import js file as config

Tags: json, react-native

I have open some config js file such as color and .. locally

```
import { Color, Images, Config } from "@common";
```

now I want to load a JSON from my server instead of  Color.js how to do this ? when I use fetch , fetch works after color applayed to elemets . I want to first load JSON then use it as like as local file ..

here is my JSON : http://size.ir/restapi/get_config
and here is my local js color :

```
export default {
  primary:  "#ff9000",
  headerTintColor: "#000",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just do fetch().then(() => require('common')

Comment: how to fetch in single file and export for all my js file ?

Comment: Well u dont need the require inside i misunderstood you.
U need to export promise
export const asyncJson=fetch(url) it will load in runtime. If u want it to act as localfile rhen u need to know the url during build time, rhen u need to creatw pipeline that would create local file so u can require it

Comment: has   any  way to   expot  that JSON az JSON object  to other files ? @repo